# How to get view dimensions in bindView in cursor adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, bind, measure

I would like to obtain `ImageView` dimensions during `bindView` method.

Unfortunately during `bindView` measured height and width are 0.

I need those dimensions to request specific image width and height from web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your AdapterView starts recycling views, the views would have not been layered-out on the  screen yet, so they will be width and height of zero, because it really is zero.

After your bindView starts to receive recycled views, they will have width and height, but then it's too late.

On those situations you must find a different way to calculate their size, for example, you can make it be a fixed value in DP for every view and just use that value. Example:

```
int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.img_size);
```

Comment: But what if I use `match_parent` ?

Comment: let's say it's a ListView that takes the whole screen with a margin of R.dimen.list_margin. So you can calculate the size by getting the `screen width - 2x (list_margin)`. But that's just an example, it depends on what your layout is.